# TypeError: .... is not a constructor in NodeJs & Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

i feel like i have read the whole internet on this, but i just cannot figure out what the problem is: i have a nodejs / typescript Project here, and need to use a Library called KDTree. from its readme i have to use it like so:

```
const { default: KDTree } = require("kd-tree-ts");
const tree = new KDTree;
```

since my through my tsconfig i need to add libraries via `ìmport ... from '...'` i do it like so:

```
import KDTree from 'kd-tree-ts'
    const tree = new KDTree
```

also tried:

```
import * as  KDTree from 'kd-tree-ts'
    const tree = new KDTree.default
```

but: on the new KDTree line i get this error: `TypeError: KDTree is not a constructor` (but it is!--> https://github.com/NickNaumenko/kd-tree-ts/blob/develop/src/kdTree.ts )
and i have just 0 idea where and what it causes. i do feel like its something in the tsconfig but for this project i cannot change it.

this is the tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "lib": [
      "es2019"
    ], 
    "module": "ESNext", 
    "rootDir": "src",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./bin",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

it anyone could point me in the right rirection it would be awesome!

Comment: Does `import KDTree from 'kd-tree-ts'` work?

Comment: isn't it exactly what i did? ;)

Comment: Right. Sorry, I missed that.

Comment: This looks like an issue with `kd-tree-ts`, the default export seems to be double-nested. It's probably worth opening an issue about it on the repo. Although I can make it work by doing `import KDTreeMod from "kd-tree-ts"; <NL> // @ts-ignore <NL> const KDTree = KDTreeMod.default; <NL> const tree = new KDTree();`, the types end up being wrong (of course) and that's very much a workaround. I've tried with `esModuleInterop` set to both `true` and `false` because it affects how the default export is handled, but it doesn't seem to help this double nesting issue. Even taking TypeScript...

Comment: ...out of the equation, there's still a double-default issue.

Answer (score 0):

Tried a minimum project and this seems to work:

```
import KDTree from 'kd-tree-ts';
const tree = new KDTree()
```

Notice that you need to use the parenthesis when doing `new KDTree()`

Comment: Although better practise, there is no mandate to instantiate with parenthesis in either JS or TS, so it's not "needed". [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeBfAUJgdvA7nIkgNxA)

Comment: How did you bootstrap that? I did a fresh project from scratch and get the same error the OP does.

Comment: This is a TS Playground with a pretty close configuration to what is posted (same target, module and related flags): https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=3&allowSyntheticDefaultImports=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAaQCIBUoFN1wGZQiOAcgGsATAWhg3UoGdCAoAYwgDtb4rM4BeOV9AHdEqagAoAlAG4GXdADpg7dLDEBtAIwAaAEwBdaUA

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "lib": [
      "es2019"
    ], 
    "module": "ESNext", 
    "rootDir": "src",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./bin",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

Add `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,` after "esModuleInterop" to support synthetic default imports.

**UPDATE:**

`kd-tree-ts` has dependency of `tslib` in build time, which indicates that `tslib` helper should be present in the app. Have you included `tslib` in your `package.json`?

Try this and see what error do you get. May be the initialization is failing before the module is exported. If you debug and catch all uncaught exceptions, see if you can get a different error.

If you can setup public repo, we can help you debug the issue.

Comment: Did you try that and have it work? I just did tried it, and it doesn't seem to solve the problem. I was **sure** you were on to something, too... :-)

Comment: does not work for me either.. sadly^^

Comment: Hi, thanks! but it does not change anything. i am still getting the same Error `TypeError: KDTree is not a constructor`

Comment: @HannesF can you setup your test case on github?